# Vectorize or optimize several nested for loops R

Tags: r, list, dataframe, matrix

I am looking to optimize code where I am using multiple `for` loops and `if` statements.

I have a dataframe:

```
set.seed(10)
df<-data.frame(val1 = c(1.1,0.2,-1.5,-2.3,2.0),
       val2 = c(0.4,0.1,-0.2,0.4,-1.1))

 df

   val1 val2
1  1.1  0.4
2  0.2  0.1
3 -1.5 -0.2
4 -2.3  0.4
5  2.0 -1.1
```

Say I also have a list, `l`

```
l <- list(
data.frame(val1 = runif(5,-3,3),
       val2 = runif(5,-2,2)),
data.frame(val1 = runif(5,-3,3),
       val2 = runif(5,-2,2)),
data.frame(val1 = runif(5,-3,3),
       val2 = runif(5,-2,2))
)

l

[[1]]
     val1       val2
1  0.04486922 -1.0982535
2 -1.15938896 -0.9018779
3 -0.43855400 -0.9107797
4  1.15861249  0.4633172
5 -2.48918419 -0.2813139

[[2]]
    val1       val2
1  0.9099340 -0.2847623
2  0.4064265 -1.7923867
3 -2.3189461 -0.9432893
4  0.5755518 -0.4048371
5 -0.8517001  1.3445366

[[3]]
    val1       val2
1  2.1883274  0.8265877
2  0.6921145  1.3531507
3  1.6506594 -1.0416435
4 -0.8665879  1.0830861
5 -0.5649002 -0.5764090
```

Every dataframe within each element of the list has the same number of rows and columns as the dataframe `df`.  What I want to do is, if a number in `df` is positive, is to count all the times that numbers in the corresponding row and column of each dataframe in the list are more positive.  Conversely, if a number in `df` is negative, I want to count the number of times that the corresponding number in each dataframe's row and columns is more negative (i.e. smaller, has a higher magnitude).

For example, the number in row 3, column 2 of `df` is -0.2. It is negative. Looking at the numbers in row 3, column 2 of each dataframe, we have -0.91, -0.94, -1.04. These are all more negative (smaller), so we should get 3.  In row 1, column 1 in `df` we have 1.1.  In row 1, column 1 of all the other dataframes, we have 0.04, 0.91, 2.19.  So we should get 1, as only one number is more positive.

I wrote nested for loops and if statements to do this:

```
mat = matrix(0, nrow=5, ncol = 2)

for(i in 1:3){
for(c in 1:2){
  for(r in 1:5){
    if(df[r,c]>0){
  if(l[[i]][r,c]>df[r,c]){
    mat[r,c] = mat[r,c]+1
  }    
    } else
      if(l[[i]][r,c]<df[r,c]){
        mat[r,c] = mat[r,c]+1
      }
  }  
}
}
```

`mat` is the desired output:

```
mat

      [,1] [,2]
 [1,]    1    1
 [2,]    2    1
 [3,]    1    3
 [4,]    0    2
 [5,]    0    0
```

Any help in speeding up this process and not relying on these loops would be appreciated.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

We can directly subtract the two data frames where the `abs`olute value in the list must be greater than the `abs`olute value in the `df`, and at the same time, their `sign` must be equal. The result would be logical, we can use `Reduce` to sum up the logical matrices.

```
Reduce(`+`, lapply(l, \(x) {
  (abs(x) > abs(df) & sign(x) == sign(df))
  }))

     val1 val2
[1,]    1    1
[2,]    2    1
[3,]    1    3
[4,]    0    2
[5,]    0    0
```

Answer (score 4):

I think you can do this using vectorized comparisons across 3-dim arrays:

```
library(abind)

a <- abind(l,along = 3)
df3 <- abind(df,df,df,along = 3)

apply(abs(a) > abs(df3) & (sign(a) == sign(df3)),
      MARGIN = 1:2,
      FUN = sum)
```

Additionally, you can create the replicated version of `df` without typing out `df` multiple times via:

```
df3 <- abind(replicate(3,df,simplify = FALSE),along = 3)
```

...or directly just by feeding a repeated vector of values to `array`:

```
df3 <- array(rep(c(as.matrix(df)),times = 3),dim = c(5,2,3))
```

Comment: interesting - thanks.  If my list `l` has e.g. 10,000 elements. Would there be a way to write the second line of code, without having to manually write out `df` thousands of times?

Comment: @jalapic Yes, maybe `abind(replicate(3,df,simplify = FALSE),along = 3)`?

Comment: @jalapic There's probably a way to create it directly using `array` and just the vector of elements in `df` as well, repeating it multiple times, but my brain isn't doing the dimensional calculations well on a Friday.